# Awful predictions of RNN while MSE is very low

Tags: predictive-modeling, rnn, loss-function

I have encountered a strange situation where the predictions of RNN are just awful despite the fact that NN has found a minimum of loss function at 0.002 for training and 0.0013-0.0015 for validation data.

My data set consists of 12470 samples with 60 time steps each.
I've used sklearn shuffling method for every prepared dataset (x_train, y_train etc)
like this:

```
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test = shuffle(x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid, x_test, y_test, random_state=0 )
```

The model looks like this:

```
n_neurons = 64
epochs = 150
lr = 0.0001
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(n_neurons, activation='elu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=[None, 1], kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(n_neurons, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(n_neurons, activation='selu', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.SimpleRNN(n_neurons, kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_regularizer='l2', bias_regularizer='l2', kernel_initializer=initializer, bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal)
])

np.random.randn(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=64,
                    validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid))
```

I am aware of the fact that He initialization is not optimal for tanh, I was just changing activation functions during testing of my model, to see which one will fit.

Now I've tested learning rates from range (0.0001 to 0.0009) with steps 0.0001.
But after x epochs models with these learning rates were stuck at 0.03 mse loss and than changed to NaN.
Learning rate of 0.0001 appears to be the best (in this very moment I am testing lower learning rates).

As I wrote above this learning rate appears to be the best due to two facts:

1. has found a minimum
2. the loss curve is ideal
   [image: loss and one prediction]

But as you see the prediction is awful, the NN only kind of get's the 'range' it should be in.

More examples below:

[image]

What is causing such a bad performance of the RNN? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you right, you are trying to predict the absolute price, and not just the change in price from the last time step. This task is much more difficult than just predicting the change in price from the previous time step, as the net accurately needs to memorize what the price in the previous time steps were. I suggest you calculate the log returns from each time step to the next and input these values into the RNN. The log return at time step t is equal to `log(price(t)/price(t-1))`. The log is a small addition, which can help as log returns are additive (they still reflect the price change after adding log returns of different time steps together). Then your model could predict a change in price from the most recent time step.
This is one way of doing this, but remember that predicting prices is not a trivial task and "good results" are very hard to achive.

Comment: Thank you, you're a genius!
I've marked your answer :)